# Catch Exception of AsyncTask. Need Thinking

Tags: android, exception

I want to catch exception of a thread in doInBackground and print the error message in onPostExcecute. The problem is I don't have the Throwable object in onPostExecute. How to **catch Exception in non-UI thread** and **print the error message in UI-thread**?

```
public class TestTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<String>> {

    @Override
    protected List<String> doInBackground(final Void... params) {
        try {
            ...
            return listOfString;
        } catch(SomeCustomException e) {
            ...
            return null;
        }       
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final List<String> result) {
        if(result == null) {
            // print the error of the Throwable "e".
            // The problem is I don't have the Throwable object here! So I can't check the type of exception.
        }

    }
}
```

**Update after Arun's answer:**

This is my AsyncTask wrapper class. It intends to do handling Exception in doInBackground but I can't find a good solution to do it.

```
public abstract class AbstractWorkerTask<Params, Progress, Result>
extends AsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result>
implements Workable {
    protected OnPreExecuteListener onPreExecuteListener;
    protected OnPostExecuteListener<Result> onPostExecuteListener;
    protected ExceptionHappenedListener exceptionHappendedListener;
    private boolean working;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        if (onPreExecuteListener != null) {
            onPreExecuteListener.onPreExecute();
        }
        working = true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final Result result) {
        working = false;
        if(/* .........*/ ) {
            exceptionHappendedListener.exceptionHappended(e);
        }
        if (onPostExecuteListener != null) {
            onPostExecuteListener.onPostExecute(result);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isWorking() {
        return working;
    }

    public void setOnPreExecuteListener(final OnPreExecuteListener onPreExecuteListener) {
        this.onPreExecuteListener = onPreExecuteListener;
    }

    public void setOnPostExecuteListener(final OnPostExecuteListener<Result> onPostExecuteListener) {
        this.onPostExecuteListener = onPostExecuteListener;
    }

    public void setExceptionHappendedListener(final ExceptionHappenedListener exceptionHappendedListener) {
        this.exceptionHappendedListener = exceptionHappendedListener;
    }

    public interface OnPreExecuteListener {
        void onPreExecute();
    }

    public interface OnPostExecuteListener<Result> {
        void onPostExecute(final Result result);
    }

    public interface ExceptionHappenedListener {
        void exceptionHappended(Exception e);
    }
}
```

Comment: you can implement some sort of callbacks to set and get error.

Comment: I tried it but I can't return both Exception and List<String> in doInBackground. How to do it?

Comment: try returning `e.toString()` instead of `null` from `catch` of `doInBackground()`...

Comment: @GAMA: hey you can't because the return type is List<String>, not String. Syntax error of course.

Comment: Mate, I meant store `e.ToString()` to 1st location of list and then check the same in `onPostExecute()`...

Comment: you can use `Exception` object insted of `List<String>` and return e.

Comment: @Siddhesh - This will work only if each and every time Exception occurs. What if code works fine? :)

Comment: @GAMA: What condition will you check in onPostExcecute if you return a List<String> contains the e.toString(). :-?? It's not possible.

Comment: @GAMA ohh yes you are right. may be you can make `List<String>` object in catch fill it with exception message, exception class, source and return that list object.

Comment: @Emerald214 - You can store somewhat like this : `"Exception"+e.toString()` in 1st location of list and then check if 1st location of list starts with `"Exception"`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change the return type of `doInBackground()` to `Object` and when you receive the result in `onPostExecute(Object result)` use the `instanceOf` operator to check if the returned result is an `Exception` or the `List<String>`.

**Edit**

Since the result can either be an Exception or else the proper List, you can use the following:

```
protected void onPostExecute(final Object result) {
    working = false;
    if(result instanceof SomeCustomException) {
        exceptionHappendedListener.exceptionHappended(result);
    }
    else{
        if (onPostExecuteListener != null) {
            onPostExecuteListener.onPostExecute(result);
        }
    }
}
```

Also change the following statement:

```
public abstract class AbstractWorkerTask<Params, Progress, Object> extends AsyncTask<Params, Progress, Object>
```

Comment: This is good but doesn't solve the problem because you can't instanceof parameterized type (List<String>). :[

Answer (score 4):

Just store the Exception into a list and handle it later, as onPostExecute() is always called after doInBackground():

```
public class TestTask extends AsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result> {

  List<Exception> exceptions = new ArrayList<Exception>();

  @Override
  protected Result doInBackground(Params... params) {
    try {
      ...
    } catch(SomeCustomException e) {
      exceptions.add(e);
    }
    return result;
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPostExecute(Result result) {
    for (Exception e : exceptions) {
      // Do whatever you want for the exception here
      ...
    }
  }

}
```

This is doable but rarely used, as in most situation, we want handle the exception as soon as it get thrown and catched:

```
public class TestTask extends AsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result> {

  @Override
  protected Result doInBackground(Params... params) {
    try {
      ...
    } catch(SomeCustomException e) {
      // If you need update UI, simply do this:
      runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
          // update your UI component here.
          myTextView.setText("Exception!!!");
        }
      });
    }
    return result;
  }

}
```

Hope this make sense.

Answer (score 4):

Changing the return type of `doInBackground` to `Object` to possibly pass an `Exception` and then use `instanceof()` is a source of code smell (bad programming practice). It is always preferable to restrict your return type to the very specific thing you want returned.

Based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14211991/2926226) simply add a private member to store the exception thrown in `doInBackground` and then check for it first thing in `onPostExecute`.

Only one `Exception` need be caught because you should stop the actions in `doInBackground` immediately once the exception is thrown and handle it gracefully in `onPostExecute` where you have access to the UI elements and so can inform the user of the mishap.

Generic example (body of the AsyncTask):

```
private Exception mException

@Override
protected Result doInBackground(Params... params) {
    try {
          // --- Do something --- //
    }
    catch( SomeException e ){ mException = e; return null; }
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Result result) {
    if (mException != null) {
        // --- handle exception --- //
        return;
    }

    // --- Perform normal post execution actions --- //
}
```