# Android, how to display a dialog from error of a try catch?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, try-catch

In my app I connect to a website to collect some information at start with a AsyncTask, using a try catch, from here I can display in my catlog the error if any at connection, but I have been trying with out luck to show a dialog displaying the connection failure with options to reconnect or quit, please check my code and tell me what I'm doing wrong or an idea of how to accomplish this

```
 //this is our download file asynctask
class DownloadFileAsync extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        showDialog(DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... aurl) {

        try {
        String result = "";
                    try {
                        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://mywebsiteaddress");
                        // httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                        InputStream webs = entity.getContent();
                        // convert response to string
                        try {
                            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                                    new InputStreamReader(webs, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
                            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                            String line = null;
                            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                                sb.append(line + "\n");
                            }
                            webs.close();

                            result = sb.toString();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
                    }

                    // parse json data
                    try {
                        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
                        for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            webResult resultRow = new webResult();
                            //infotodownload
                            arrayOfWebData.add(resultRow);

                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
                    }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // this is the line of code that sends a real error message to the
        // log
        Log.e("ERROR", "ERROR IN CODE: " + e.toString());
        // this is the line that prints out the location in
        // the code where the error occurred.
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
         Log.d(LOG_TAG,progress[0]);
         mProgressDialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String unused) {
        //dismiss the dialog after the file was downloaded
        dismissDialog(DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS);
    }

}

//our progress bar settings
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
        case DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS: //we set this to 0
            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
            mProgressDialog.setTitle("Conectando al Servidor");
            mProgressDialog.setMessage("Cargando informacion...");
            mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            mProgressDialog.setMax(100);
            mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
            mProgressDialog.setCancelable(true);
            mProgressDialog.show();
            return mProgressDialog;
        default:
            return null;
    }
}
```

EDIT:
then I have try adding the next code as of suggested by Arun

```
 catch (Exception e) {
        // this is the line of code that sends a real error message to the
        // log
        Log.e("ERROR", "ERROR IN CODE: " + e.toString());
        // this is the line that prints out the location in
        // the code where the error occurred.
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "ERROR_IN_CODE";
    }
       return null;       // if I place here return "ERROR_IN_CODE" it calls the dialog but it gets always called so I don't need it here
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String unused) {
        //dismiss the dialog after the file was downloaded
        dismissDialog(DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS);
        if(unused.equals("ERROR_IN_CODE")){                 //I get a system crash here!
            errornote();
        }
    }

}

public void errornote() {
    AlertDialog.Builder alt_bld = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alt_bld.setMessage("No se a podido descargar la informacion de los medios, deseas reintentarlo, o salir?").setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Conectar de Nuevo", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    new DownloadFileAsync().execute();
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("Salir", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    // Action for 'NO' Button
                    finish();
                }
            });
    AlertDialog alert = alt_bld.create();
    // Title for AlertDialog
    alert.setTitle("Error en la Conexion!");
    // Icon for AlertDialog
    alert.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert);
    alert.show();
}
```

but not working either, my app crashes in the if statement line in onPostExecute. I still need help.

Comment: You can't show the dialog in the Catch block of doInBackground() because this function runs in a non-UI thread

Comment: See if the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10944442/catch-exception-of-asynctask-need-thinking/10947623#10947623) helps.

Comment: @yorkw, no the dialog doesn't show.

Comment: According to you last EDIT, it seems code execution doesn't run into catch block, make sure you catch block is triggered properly, in another word, make sure the code in try block failed and throw the actual exception.

Comment: @ yorkw, what I have done to test it is just disconnect my internet from the computer that way when the emulator try's to connect to download the info it won't be able to so it will get an connection error. is that what you meant?

Comment: @zvzej, if you only want to test if runOnUiThread() works in doInBackground(), simply move it from catch block to try block (first line in try block), you will see the effect. I don't know much about you requirements so can't tell if disconnect internet would trigger catch block properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are returning a String object from the `protected String doInBackground(String... aurl)` return some custom Error String from the catch block and access it in the `protected void onPostExecute(String unused)`. Check if the returned String object is the Custom Error String and show the dialog in `protected void onPostExecute(String unused)` but only after dismissing the progressDialog i.e. after this line `dismissDialog(DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS);` show the error dialog.

**EDIT**

When the control enters the Catch block return some simple String like the one you used "ERROR_IN_CODE".

```
catch (Exception e) {
    // this is the line of code that sends a real error message to the
    // log
    Log.e("ERROR", "ERROR IN CODE: " + e.toString());
    // this is the line that prints out the location in
    // the code where the error occurred.
    e.printStackTrace();

    return "ERROR_IN_CODE";
}
```

And in the `onPostExecute(String unused)` check for the following

```
protected void onPostExecute(String unused) {
    //dismiss the dialog after the file was downloaded
    dismissDialog(DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS);
    if(unused != null && unused.equals("ERROR_IN_CODE")){
        showDialog(SOME_DIALOG_TO_SHOW_ERROR);
    }
}
```

Comment: @ Arun Thanks for all the information, I like your approach to my question, but I'm kind of new to all this, could you give me a sample on how to implement the custom Error String in my code? thanks

Comment: @ Arun, I have try it but it keeps crashing the app, in the logcat gives me an error at line 410 where I have the if(unused.equals.....

Comment: @zvzej why are you returning a null after the Catch block? I suppose you should be returning the result String if you don't encounter any error. Anyway I have edited the onPostExecute(String unused) and have added the null check and this should solve your problem.

Comment: @ Arun, this got it done! thanks a lot!, in the return null I can only say that I got this part of the code from a tutorial online and thats the way it was there and it worked in my case. I just had to ad the  return "ERROR_IN_CODE"; to al the catch cases in the Asynctask so it could be called in any error case. Again thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Try calling your activities runOnUiThread() method

```
activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            //your alert dialog builder here
    });
```

Comment: @ ian, where and how should I implement this?

Comment: @yorkw, could you explain me how or where to use this?

Comment: @zvzej, suppose you implement your AsyncTask as a inner class of Activity, check out sample code [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10944442/catch-exception-of-asynctask-need-thinking/10947623#10947623).

Answer (score 0):

you are not using the `builder` to create AlertDialog
remove the line `builder.show()` and add

```
AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
alert.show();
```

I will also recommend that do the UI updates through `progressUpdate()` or `preExecute()` and 'postExecute()' of the asyc task.

Implementation

```
@ReactMethod
    public void showCustomAlert(String msg){

        final String message = msg;

        this.reactContext.runOnUiQueueThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                AlertDialog.Builder myDialogBox = new AlertDialog.Builder(reactContext.getCurrentActivity());
                myDialogBox.setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#0037FF'>Konnect</font>"));
                myDialogBox.setMessage(message);
                myDialogBox.setCancelable(true);
                myDialogBox.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){

                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                    }

                });
                AlertDialog alertDialog = myDialogBox.create();
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= 23) {
                    alertDialog.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);
                }else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                    alertDialog.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY);
                }else {
                    alertDialog.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE);
                }

                alertDialog.show();

                WindowManager.LayoutParams wmlp = alertDialog.getWindow().getAttributes();
                wmlp.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
                wmlp.x = 25;   //x position
                wmlp.y = 450;   //y position
                wmlp.height = 380;
                alertDialog.show();
                alertDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.WHITE));
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: AlertDialog.Builder.show() does exactly the same thing you suggest here. It's just a shorter variant. See [the source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/android/app/AlertDialog.java#AlertDialog.Builder.show%28%29).

Comment: How can you show a dialog in doInBackground() since it runs on a non-UI thread?

Comment: Sorry @Orlymee I was still writing the comment when you edited your post. I want to remove my downvote but it shows a dialog saying "You last voted on this answer
8 mins ago
Your vote is now locked in
unless this answer is edited"

Comment: @ Orlymee, could you give me a sample using my code on how to implement your idea. thanks